# in Spring.config, can I define object of type string?

Tags: .net, spring, spring.net

Can I do something like this:

```
  <object id="mydb" type="string">
    <value>"blah"</value> <-- note that <value> tag does not really exist
  </object>
```

So that I could use it later like so:

```
  <object id="Someobject" type="Sometype">
    <property name="ConnectionString" ref="mydb"/>
  </object>
```

EDIT: this was SpringFramework.NET solution I was looking for. Looks like PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer exists there too. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Spring's built-in [PropertyPlaceholdConfigurer](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html):

```
<bean id="PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
   <property name="location" value="classpath*:/application.properties"/>
</bean>

 <bean id="Someobject" class="somepackage.Sometype">
   <property name="connectionString" value="${mydb}"/>
 </bean>
```

Setting `SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE` allows overriding the property via the command line.

Comment: +1 - PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer what I use, except for the system properties override.  No need for that in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Use placeholders eg **${magic}** and define the key/value in a properties file along with a PostProcessor. Google for *spring post processor placeholder*...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any advantage to your way at all.  It's all still just configuration.

Sometimes people externalize database connection strings to a .properties file and get at them that way.  I think that makes more sense than your proposal.

Comment: The advantage is to not have the same string specified in 300 places in your dozen config files.

Comment: No advantage at all - I don't have anything more than once, and I don't have dozens of config files.  You're not using Spring properly if you do.

Comment: I have a solution with ~25 projects. Some of the projects implement libraries used in a few other projects.